# libGDX - Can while loop cause hangs

Tags: java, libgdx

While looking for some ligGDX-related information I found [this page](http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=34846.0).
What drew my attention is this sentence:

> No, don't use a while loop. Might cause hangs.

My question is: Is it true? If it's true, why? I would assume that it has something to do with garbage collector, but I'm not sure why a while loop would require more gc attention than a for loop.

Comment: All looping operators can cause _hangs_ if the exit condition is never meet.

Comment: @munyul Right. However my understanding of this sentence is that it can **generally** cause hangs, not in specific (and obvious) cases. Although you may have a point as it's easier to create an infinite loop by mistake in while than in for.

Comment: As far as I know, the only real difference between a `for` loop and a `while` loop is that the `for` loop _asks_ you to provide initial, exit and increment _conditions_. Which makes it a little _safer_ from _programmer_ error, if you understand what I mean...

Comment: @munyul Yes, I understand what you mean and you're absolutely right. I'm just not sure if this is what the author meant.

Comment: you can make eternal for loops as easily as with while or do-while loops, so for it's not safer. It is more readable, though, since initialization and next-iteration-changes are separated from the instructions block

Comment: @dtortola I think this is what munyul meant (see also his/her answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `while` loop is as safe as any other loop. All loop types like `for(;;)`, `do-while` and `while` will in the end result in pretty similar code.

The only exception is the `for-each` loop. A for-each loop works only on things that are `Iterable`. What happens in the background is the creation of an `Iterator` and the use of its `hasNext()` and `next()` methods to iterate.

The problem with this is that it results in a small overhead. In most common implementations of the Java collections, a new `Iterator` object is created for each execution of a loop. If a for-each loop runs very often, the garbage collection might really become a problem and cause small lags.

Since there is the [libgdx] tag in your question, I assume you are familiar with the replacement collections that LibGDX offers. For example `Array` or `ObjectSet` try to avoid exactly the problem I've mentioned, by **re-using** their iterators.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the replacement collections, partially thanks to your answer to [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28428671/libgdx-array-class-benefits) :-) However in the thread where I found this sentence we only have a regular for (not for-each) and while and apparently the first one is superior in terms of performance. Perhaps it's simply not true :-)

Comment: I don't see any reason why any loop, besides the for-each loop would cause lags/hangs. Of course it always depends on what you are actually doing in your loops, but only the existance of a `while` loop, instead of a simple for `loop`, cannot be responsible for any performance issues.

Comment: Thanks. Together with the above comment this is the answer I'm accepting.

Answer (score 1):

As I already commented, I believe the only real difference between a `for` loop and a `while` loop is that the `for` loop asks you to provide *initial*, *exit* and *increment* information. Which I guess makes it a little *safer* from programmer *forgetfulness*.

As for why that user (Gibbo3771) from the post you linked said "*don't use a while loop*", it is possibly because (s)he was talking about the post from DonDon. In DonDon's post there is the following `while` loop example:

```
While (i=0 ;i <= deadBlock.size){
block1 = deadBlock(i)
block2 = deadBlock(i+1)
}
```

In this *psuedo* code from DonDon the variable `i` is set to 0, but is never incremented, which in this case would cause an endless loop (hang). It is possible, this is what Gibbo3771 was actually referring to.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I would never understand this sentence this way. (S)he wrote: _No, don't use **a** while loop. **Might** cause hangs._ If (s)he meant what you suggested it would be something like this: _Don't use the while loop. It will hang the application._ (and probably also something about the missing incrementation).

Comment: There are any number of reasons why Gibbo3771 might have written it like that, maybe (s)he was in a hurry, maybe English is not his/her mother-tongue, etc... If it is really bugging you, write a message to Gibbo3771 in those forums and ask, if you're lucky you'll get a reply (one that you like ;))

Comment: Thanks for your answer and advice, but if this user really meant that, then I really don't care :-) My question was if in libGDX you shouldn't use while loops as they can cause hangs, in opposite to for(;;) loops. The answer from user noone together with his comment explained me that it's not the case.