# Adding an instance to an array LibGDX

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist, libgdx

I am trying to make it so in a level map, whenever there is a "g", a new `Ground` instance is appended to an ArrayList. When I use the `.add()` method, it appears that the array list resets after every call of the function. Here is my code:

```
package com.mygdx.thetimetraveller;

import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Game implements Screen {
    SpriteBatch batch = new SpriteBatch();

    List<Ground> groundList = new ArrayList<Ground>();

    String[] level = {
        "                    ",
        "                    ",
        "                    ",
        "                    ",
        "                    ",
        "                    ",
        "      g             ",
        "g                   ",
        "ggggggggggggg ggg gg",
        "g                   "
    };

    Game(SpriteBatch batch) {
        this.batch = batch;
        this.load();
    }

    @Override
    public void load() {
        for(int c = 0; c < level.length; c ++){
            for(int r = 0; r < level[c].length(); r ++){
                switch(level[c].charAt(r)) {
                    case 'g':
                        groundList.add(new Ground(r * 108, c * 108, this.batch));
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void display() {
        for(int i = 0; i < groundList.size(); i ++) {
            groundList.get(i).Draw();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this, only one ground block shows up, and that's the last "g" in the array (bottom row, first character). So, how exactly can I make it so a new instance is pushed into the arraylist? Or, is there an alternative to the arraylist that I can use? Overall, I wanna be able to loop through whatever list there is and call the `.Draw()` method on each instance appended in the nested for loops in the `load()` method. I know there are many StackOverflow forums of people asking how to append to an arraylist in regular java, but LibGDX acts different, so I can't find any help for it. Thanks in advance!

That code is in "Game.java". Here is the rest of the code:
"Main.java":

```
package com.mygdx.thetimetraveller;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

public class Main extends ApplicationAdapter {
    SpriteBatch batch;
    OrthographicCamera camera;
    Screen gameState;

    private int gameScene = 4;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        gameState = new Game(batch);
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(true, 1920, 1080);
        Assets.imagesLoad();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose () {
        batch.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        switch (gameScene) {
            case 1:
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
            case 4:
                gameState = new Game(batch);
                break;
        }
        camera.update();
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        batch.begin();
            gameState.display();
        batch.end();
    }
}
```

"Ground.java":

```
package com.mygdx.thetimetraveller;

import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

public class Ground extends GameBlock {
    Ground(double x, double y, SpriteBatch batch) {
        setX(x);
        setY(y);
        setBatch(batch);
    }

    @Override
    public void Draw() {
        batch.draw(Assets.simpleBlockTexture01_sprite, (float) x, (float) y);
    }
}
```

"GameBlock.java":

```
package com.mygdx.thetimetraveller;

import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

public abstract class GameBlock {
    protected static double x;
    protected static double y;
    protected static SpriteBatch batch = new SpriteBatch();

    public void setX(double x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public void setY(double y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
    public double getX() {
        return this.x;
    }
    public double getY() {
        return this.y;
    }
    public void setBatch(SpriteBatch batch) {
        this.batch = batch;
    }
    public abstract void Draw();
}
```

"Screen.java":

```
package com.mygdx.thetimetraveller;

public interface Screen {
    void load();
    void display();
}
```

I'm still leaving out the unnecessary classes for this situation, like the other object classes and the assets class.

Comment: A little tip: Use the libgdx `Array` class instead of `ArrayList`. The Libgdx Collections are optimized to [avoid garbage collection](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28428956/3182091) , so they might give you a little FPS-Boost, at least on mobile devices.

Comment: ArrayList behaves the same in Libgdx as it does anywhere else. Try adding a toString method to your Ground class and logging the list toString() to narrow down what's wrong.

Comment: By the way, you are instantiating a throw-away sprite batch outside the class constructor, and it will leak memory since it's never disposed of.

Comment: What exactly does that mean? Should I dispose of the SpriteBatch? I already am in the main class, and that spritebatch is set to the spritebatch of each class using it.

Comment: So, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you add those grounds to a list? Why are yuou not using your array to draw what you need directly? I would opt for a multidimentional array too. Have a look at the following:

```
String[][] level = {
  {"g", "r", "g"},
  {" ", "x", "t"},
  //...
};

for (int y = 0; y < level[0].length; y++)
{
  for (int x = 0; x < level.length; x++)
  {
      if (level[x][y].equals("g"))
        draw(groundTile, x * tilewidth, y * tileheight);
      else if (level[x][y].equals("x"))
        draw(otherTile, x * tilewidth, y * tileheight);
  }
}
```

This is especially handy when you have large levels. You exactly know what to draw based on camera position, resolution and tilesize. Now you just have to iterate over the necessary part of the array instead over the whole list.

Comment: I'm adding instances to the list because of efficiency.

Comment: So, is there no way to do what I asked for?

Comment: I do not see why your method would be more efficient. An arraylist is essentially an array with a tiny bit overheat.  Your code as is should work as far as I can tell. Try debugging and keep a close eye on your arraylist.

Comment: I've tried many, many, many things. If I go with method, than I'd have to repeat lines of code. That is the main reason I said its more efficient. Also, if I go with your method, variables wouldn't be able to change. For example, I have a situation where there is an `alive` boolean for the object (like an enemy). If I say `alive = false;` when something happens to kill the enemy, then nothing would happen. Overall, I wanna be able to add enemies, bosses, regular block, maybe some lava blocks or spikes, etc, in the most efficient way possible. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why would/could nothing happen to an object in a normal array? Obviously I do not know the bigger picture of your goal but `map[x][y].setAlive(false)` would be the same as `map.get(mapWidth * y + x).setAlive`. I do not see why you have to repeat lines of code, or what you mean by that.

Comment: But why do you want to add all different kind of objects to the same list? An enemy should have his own position and not be static like a tile on your map. You should have a list of your tiles separated from enemies and perhaps separate power-ups and moving objects too. You would read you map file a single time and put that in a multi dimensional array.

Comment: Yes, I do want different lists for each object. But I'm kind of confused on `map.get(mapWidth * y + x).setAlive`. What I meant is the boolean `alive` gets set to false in this class.

Comment: And I am exactly showing you how to set that boolean to false with a single `ArrayList` vs a `Array[][]`. If the field alive is public you could simply do `.alive = true` but making everything public without getters and setters is often not a good choice. I think your real problem is not understanding basic java and that results in flawed communication. I have always done my tilemaps with the method I show in my answer and currently I do not see why an `ArrayList` would be helpful here.

Comment: I'm not saying I need to use ArrayList. In fact, I could do pretty well without it. But I still don't think your code would work out. Nonetheless, I'm still sort of confused on how to actually use it. I updated the question to add some more important code. Hope it helps to find a way that I can do what I am trying.

Comment: Well I don't think my code could be any simpler. `X` represents horizontal tiles/blocks and `Y` represents vertical blocks. That makes a multidimentional array `map[X][Y]` very suitable for such a task. In my answer I show you how to create it and loop it. To draw a block you just loop the array and draw it however you want. Anyway, you are creating a ton of unnecessary static SpriteBatch objects. Just sent the `SpriteBatch` you use to the `draw()` method each frame instead of the constructor and putting it in it's own field to just use it only in `draw()`.

Comment: I was also having trouble understanding the array you used in your example. What exactly is the equivalent to my array in your method?

Comment: As for the last sentence of your last reply, are you pretty much saying that I can do this: `Main.batch.draw();` instead of doing all of that with the constructors? Because I totally forgot about that.

Comment: Also, `frameCount` isn't increasing (in Game.java) for some reason. I apologize for all the questions and making myself look like a total idiot, but this is my first major project in libGDX using more than just a few simple classes and arrays.

Comment: My `array[][]` is a multidimentional array. A tilemap or 2D game has two dimensions as well thats why I advice to use that. Where you call `groundList.get(i).Draw();` just pass the batch as reference `groundList.get(i).Draw(batch);`. There is no need to reserve memory in each of your objects for it.

Comment: Essentially, my `Array[][]` of strings or ints already holds the position. If your tilewidth is `64` then `Array[2][0]` should be drawn at `64 * 2 = 128`. On large tilemaps you only need to draw what is on the screen and you can calculate that based on cam position, tilewidth and resolution. The string, char or int is just a reference to the type of tile if all you need is to draw that tile then just iterate and draw based on the value. There is no need for a tile class that holds the position and batch.

Comment: How about the `frameCount` issue?

Comment: Do you mean FPS by that?

Comment: I mean the `frameCount` variable in my code. I'm incrementing it, and expecting for it to continuously go up, as a frame count does. But, it goes up once and stays at 1 the entire time. Do you know why?

Comment: There is no frame count variable in the code you posted.

Comment: Oh, you're right! I updated my code since I uploaded the code to here. So, in the `Game` class, I have `public static int frameCount;`. Then I initialize it as `frameCount = 0;` in the constructor. Finally, I increment it in the `display` method. This method gets called in the main class' `render` method, so it should be repeating over and over again. But, it doesn't. Overall, I don't think any of the code is doing this. So, is there something you notice wrong with calling the `display` method in the Main class?