# Java ArrayList vs Libgdx Array

Tags: java, libgdx, cross-platform

I want to know that whether or not using **Java** specific code breaks cross platform utility. For example, does it matter I use **Java** `ArrayList` or **Libgdx** `Array`?

Comment: From the [libgdx project website](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/features.html):`Libgdx is a Java game development framework that provides a unified API that works across all supported platforms`. Your queestion is very broad as it depends on each library.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Then consider just Java ArrayList. Is it converted something equal in IOS? Do I have to worry about it?

Comment: Both work on all platforms. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28428671/libgdx-array-class-benefits

Comment: You misunderstand. The Libgdx library works on every plateform according to it's developpers. But another library may not. java `ArrayList` and Libgdx `Array` are niot libraries, they are classes **from** a library

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using general `java` collections such as the `ArrayList` will not break your code, and will work properly from a *functional* point of view. However, usually when developing games, you want to consider the *performance* as well, since wasteful programming will affect your game experience. `libgdx` developed their own collections exactly for that reason: to have collections that are better, performance wise. In general it is better to use `libgdx` collections than the standard `java` ones. Take a look at the [docs](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Collections) for more info.